# Product Images - Different Websites/Store Views

Tags: product, csv, store-view, magento-2.1.8

I've got two websites in my Magento project which got single inventory catalog. I would like to upload different images to different Websites. I managed to use store_view_code for each image. Up to Category view page, the product images are appearing right way. However, when I click on product, the product page showing both the images. I managed to update hide_from_product_page property to hide one image. However, this property is not working for me when use CSV. When I have multiple store view codes, none of the images or hiding. May I know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to set up a product manually with the correct settings (excluding images from different storeviews, assigning types, etc) and then do an export to see how it's formatted. (Haven't done this personally, but it should work unless there is a bug!)